# Using a dynamic index on Spark Structured Streaming with ES Hadoop

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I have Elasticsearch 6.4.2 and Spark 2.2.0

Currently I have a **working example** where I can send data from a Dataset into Elasticsearch via the **writeStream** (Structured Streaming) API:

```
ds.writeStream
.outputMode("append")
.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
.option("checkpointLocation","hdfs://X.X.X.X:9000/tmp")
.option("es.resource.write","index/doc")
.option("es.nodes","X.X.X.X")
.trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
.start()
```

However, I am interested in using dynamic index names to create a new [index based on the date of the event](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/time-based.html). Per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/spark.html#spark-streaming-write-dyn), it its supposedly possible to do that using the **es.resource.write** configuration with a special format:

```
.option("es.resource.write","index-{myDateField}/doc")
```

Despite all my efforts, when I try to run the code with the curly braces on, it immediately crashes stating an illegal character '{' was detected.

**¿Does the streamWrite API currently supports this configuration?**

Comment: Did you find more information on this topic?

Answer (score -1):

spark

```
.readStream
.option("sep", ",")
.schema(userSchema)
.csv("/data/csv/") // csv file home
.writeStream
.format("es")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
.option("checkpointLocation", "file:/data/job/spark/checkpointLocation/example/StructuredEs")
.start("structured.es.example.{name}.{date|yyyy-MM}") // ES 7+  no type
.awaitTermination()
```